# XPath Query With Multiple Arrays

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
<xml>
    <header>
        (Tags goes here)
    </header>
    <listItem>
        <id></id>
        ...
        (Sort of data)
        ...
        <arrayType1>
            <id></id>
            <parentId></parentId>
            <!-- Key: Data to lookup and get the entire structure (listItem) with XPath-->
            <key></key>
        </arrayType1>
        <arrayType2>
            <id></id>
            <parentId></parentId>
            <!-- Key: Data to lookup and get the entire structure (listItem) with XPath-->
            <key></key>
        </arrayType2>
    </listItem>
    <listItem>
        (Exactly same structure with different data as above)
    </listItem>
</xml>
```

Tag `<parentId>` has the same data of `<listItem><id>` tag (not to be confused with `<id>` of each arrayType).

I need a XPath expression that returns the `<parentId>` or `<listItem><id>` only having the  data (or, by default, return the entire arrayTypeX and process later in another XSLT transformation).

I need this for a transformation in a XSLT Map in IBM Integration Designer (Websphere ESB), but i'm very confused about the XPath expression, but, the point is merely in build that XPath Expression.

I've tried with this expression:

/listItem[arrayType1[key = 'value']]/parentID

But i don't know if XPath supports that kind of syntax (array inside array looking for a specific value). That expression always return the first ID of the list.

The Cardinality for each item is:

```
header: [0..1] 
listItem: [0..*]
arrayType1: [0..*]
arrayType2: [0..*]
```

Can you shed some light about this?

Thanks

EDIT: This is an example:

```
<xml>
    <header>
        (Tags goes here)
    </header>
    <listItem>
        <id>1</id>
        <arrayType1>
            <id>1000</id>
            <parentId>1</parentId>
            <key>abc</key>
        </arrayType1>
        <arrayType1>
            <id>1500</id>
            <parentId>1</parentId>
            <key>mno</key>
        </arrayType1>
        <arrayType2>
            <id>2000</id>
            <parentId>1</parentId>
            <key>def</key>
        </arrayType2>
    </listItem>
    <listItem>
        <id>2</id>
        <arrayType1>
            <id>3000</id>
            <parentId>2</parentId>
            <key>ghi</key>
        </arrayType1>
        <arrayType2>
            <id>4000</id>
            <parentId>2</parentId>
            <key>jkl</key>
        </arrayType2>
    </listItem>
</xml>
```

Only having the `<key>` (for example, "ghi"), i expect to get the `<id>` or `<parentId>` "2", with an XPath expression.

Comment: please correct this line first: `I need an XPath expression that returns the or only having the data`  and also, please provide a sample input/output that u're expecting

Comment: @sunbabaphu My mistake, it was an error in code format. Also i've attached an example of what i'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the order of `<parentId>` and `<key>` is maintained, i.e. `<parent>` appears before `<key>` in each `<arrayTypeX>` then this will work:

```
//key[text()="value"]/preceding-sibling::parentId[1]
```

for eg:
for `key = "jkl"` the return will be `2`.

though, it must be mentioned here that, if required, it can be tweaked to account for **multiple matches for `<key>`** as well as **no particular order for `<parent>` and `<key>`**.